# Can't push javascript variable into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, google-analytics, push

I want to push a javascript variable into an array. Specifically, I want to push a Google Analytics account ID (UA-XXXXXXXX-X) into the Google Analytics javascript tracking code in the footer of my site.

```
(function($) {

        var jsvars = {"columns":"1","mobilemenu":"1","googleanalytics":"UA-XXXXXXXX-X"};
        var googleanalytics = jsvars.googleanalytics;

        /* hit run to to confirm the googleanalytics variable is available */
        alert (googleanalytics);

        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        /* I want to push the googleanalytics variable into the array */
        /* When I view source, it does not show as UA-XXXXXXXX-X, it just shows as googleanalytics */
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', googleanalytics]);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();

})(jQuery);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/robflate/2MnM7/

Thanks.

Comment: Things you do in JavaScript won't show up when you do a "view source".  That just shows you what the page looked like when the browser loaded it.

Comment: Please post your code here instead of just on another site. If that link ever dies, your question will not be useful to future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending Pointy's comment to an answer, you can't use your browser's "view source" function to see what you're looking for.  "View Source" will show the JavaScript as you wrote it.  It won't show you what any of the values are at runtime, etc.  For this, you'll want a decent JavaScript debugger - now built-in to all major web browsers.  (Or use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) for Firefox.)

If you set a debugger breakpoint on this line, you'll be able to see that `googleanalytics` is `UA-XXXXXXXX-X`.  This is similar to what you already demonstrated yourself with your `alert` line.

Comment: ziesemer - Thank you for the info. I'm sure everyone who knows that javascript doesn't update the source is thinking I must be stupid but I honestly never knew that. Also, I'm using Chrome and can't work out how to see what variable is actually set using the Developer Tools.

Comment: @robflate - Open up the developer tools (F12), click on the "Scripts" tab, select your file, find the `_gaq.push(['_setAccount', googleanalytics]);` line, click on the line # next to it in the left-margin to set a breakpoint, then refresh the page.  This variable and its value should then be visible in "Scope Variables" once the breakpoint is hit.

Comment: Maybe one could think it would generate HTML output viewable in the source. Actually I think Javascript is the entrance to a whole lot more of data getting transmitting when loading a webpage.

Comment: ziesemer - Thanks for pointing that out. I tried to vote up the answer but it says my reputation is too low. I'd wrongly presumed the same applied to clicking the tick. I've rectified it now.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an improvement on the answer, but some tips for debugging Google Analytics.  The original poster mentioned that he was using chrome, which is a good thing. In chrome you can first of all pull up the JavaScript debug console using the key combo CTRL-SHIFT-J.  For Google Analytics specific information, you can also download the extension for GA debugging built for Chrome.  This extension allows you to see pretty much everything you would want to know about your Google interactions in the debug console.

Also, fiddler2 is a great resource for debugging JavaScript.  The second link below has a great video tutorial on how to use fiddler to give you a great deal of control over the http interactions, especially when using the autoresponder function to supply local copies of .js files that would normally be loaded from your web server.

A couple of links that helped me:

http://www.webanalyticsworld.net/2012/01/basics-of-debugging-google-analytics-code-ga-chrome-debugger-and-other-tools.html

http://www.webanalyticsworld.net/2012/02/debugging-google-analytics-code-ii-a-tutorial-video-on-fiddler%E2%80%99s-inspector-and-autoresponder-functions.html